# Manipulating data of each response in scrapy as a whole by combining data of all responses

Tags: python, scrapy

1. Yielded `scrapy.Request` in a loop and now I am getting responses one by one.

```
    def start_requests(self):
        for key, value in self.data_dict.items():
            urlList = value["url_list"]
            for eachURL in urlList:
                yield scrapy.Request(eachURL, callback=self.parse, meta={
                    "category":key,
                    "results":value["results"]
                })
```

2. What I am doing in parse function is getting applied to response of each response.
3. I want to manipulate the response as a whole by combining data from all responses in one.
4. I am unable to do that.
5. I searched documentation, SOF, asked ChatGPT. Didn't got satisactory answer.

Comment: You can loop inside parse method and yield the final result when there are no more pages.

Comment: You can do this by chaining together your requests, one after another, but this kind of defeats the benefits you get from using an asynchronous framework like scrapy.  You may as well just use the requests lib if this is your goal